# How to get yum to recogize new packages added to Artifactory repo?

Tags: artifactory, rpm, yum

I have a local yum repo within Artifactory that I recently added a new RPM to.  I did the recalculate index and on my client system ran `yum clean all` and `yum update`.  But when I try to install the new package it doesn't find it.  It finds all other packages that are part of the local repo in Artifactory, just not the new one.

I'm assuming this is an issue with my recalculate index not working, but haven't been able to figure out what. I also verified in the Artifactory log that the recalculate index is running to completion without errors.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It ended up being my RPM Metadata Folder Depth value was incorrect.